# Trifold mock up does not match with main document

Tags: adobe-illustrator, adobe-photoshop

[image]

I have created this trifold brochure (front) in Adobe Illustrator. After completing, I want to apply it on mock up.

I opened a smart object for a specifically assigned part and then  saved it.

But the finishing is not good at all. Waves are not matching with one another!

Am I doing something wrong, or is there some specific process for work like this??

What I tried:

1. Copy / paste from Illustrator to Photoshop mock.
2. I opened JPEG in Photoshop, then sliced it in equal parts, and copy / paste it on brochure.

Comment: minor comment: the cover of the brochure in the mockup appears to be *inside* the brochure if it were folded.

Answer (score 1):

And what's stopping you from placing each side as a separate layer and adjusting these manually until they fit correctly? It looks like you're doing it right, just need to shift the middle fold a bit to the left.

Comment: OMG!! holding shift solved it!!!! thank you so much!!! am screaming in joy!!!! thank you!!